# Taking an Error while trying to find LAST_VALUE() in impala

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to find the last blnc value of each id but it throws me an error:

> AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation
> output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): last_value(blnc) OVER
> (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
> AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) lasted.

```
SELECT id, number, type,
    LAST_VALUE(blnc) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) AS lasted ,
    to_timestamp(MAX(date),'yyyyMMdd') as end_date,
    concat(substr(date,1,6),"01") as start_date,
    substr(date,1,6) as id_month
FROM table
GROUP BY id,number,type,concat(substr(date,1,6),"01"),substr(date,1,6)
```

I put all the LAST_VALUE() statement in the `group by` also but another error occurs.

Comment: Window function `LAST_VALUE() OVER ()` doesn't work with `GROUP BY`. Option 1. remove group by. Option 2. remove `OVER()`. Choose option depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your expression:

```
   LAST_VALUE(blnc) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                          ORDER BY date
                          rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
                          ) AS lasted ,
```

is scoped to run *after* the aggregation.  So, only expressions that are understood after the aggregation are valid.  And there is no `date` or `blnc`.  You can fix this by using aggregation functions:

```
   LAST_VALUE(MAX(blnc)) OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                               ORDER BY MAX(date)
                               rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
                              ) AS lasted ,
```

Although this answers your question and fixes the syntax error, it probably doesn't do anything useful.  I think you want conditional aggregation.  You haven't explained the logic you want or provided sample data, but the idea is:

```
SELECT id, number, type,
       to_timestamp(MAX(date), 'yyyyMMdd') as end_date,
       concat(substr(date,1,6),"01") as start_date,
       substr(date, 1, 6) as id_month,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN blnc END) as lasted
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, number, type, concat(substr(date, 1, 6), '01'), substr(date,1,6)
                                ORDER BY date DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
GROUP BY id, number, type, concat(substr(date, 1, 6), '01'), substr(date,1,6)
```

Note:  String operations on dates look wrong.  You should be using the built-in date/time functions, if the column is stored correctly.